# Why Texture Unit number is limited in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures, shader

As I understand we store texture in GPU memory with glTexImage2D function and there is no limited number theoretically. However, when we try to use them there is a limitation which is 32 texture units GL_TEXTURE0 to GL_TEXTURE31. Why is there this limitation?

Comment: Traditionally, each texture unit might apply an operation on a fragment. This meant that only so many units could be applied to maintain a pixel fill rate; and those texture units took up silicon real-estate, contended for texture memory, etc. (I am simplifying things here). More importantly, the fact that 0 .. 31 are enumerated doesn't mean they exist in your GL implementation. You query these with `glGet` functions, e.g., `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`.

Comment: You might be interested in [*GLview*](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/), which can report the actual capabilities, limits, extensions, etc., via querying.

Comment: `ARB_bindless_texture` supports accessing any number of textures without binding them at all, on hardware that supports it.

Comment: Those are just binding locations, the GL spec. (3.0 onward) provides a minimum of 16 per-shader stage. That doesn't mean that because you have 80 different places to bind textures (in GL 4.5) that you can use 80 of them in a single shader invocation :) They merely provide enough locations that you could uniquely bind 16 different textures for each stage. There's a secondary limitation for that.

Answer (score 1):

The limitation in question (which as mentioned in the comments, is the wrong limit) is on the number of textures that can be used with a single rendering command at one time. Each shader stage has [its own limit on the number of textures it can access](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader#Resource_limitations).

This limitation exists because hardware is not unlimited in its capabilities. Textures require resources, and some hardware has limits on how many of these resources can be used at once. Just like hardware has limits on the number of uniforms a shader stage can have and so forth.

Now, there is some hardware which is capable of accessing texture data in a more low-level way. This functionality is exposed via the ARB_bindless_texture. It's not a core feature because not all recent, GL 4.x-capable hardware can support it.